# Issues with semaphore and Multi-Threading a Process.Start

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

Not sure what the problem is with my code below, but not working as expected.  The design is to allow the user to select any number of input files from a ListBox and click an 'Execute' button to kick off the same executable using a different input file.  I will be adding a control to allow the user to specify the number of concurrent processes, but for now I'm hard-coding to 3 for testing.  My expectation is each executable will start in order (though I understand they may not finish that way) and only 3 will execute at a time (though this number will eventually be controlled by a user input control).  I would like to additional functionality to the function calling the process i.e. task priority, return exitcode, but for now I'm not able to get the basic functionality working.  I've tried many variations of code I've found on this site and others on the web, but still cannot get it to work.  Here is the current version:

```
    private void btnParserExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pool = new Semaphore(3,3);  //Pool above declared as class variable 
        string ExeName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Norman\\bin\\OC2.exe";
        string Args;
        string ArgDir = this.dirListBox1.Path + "\\";

        for (int i = 0; i < this.fileListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.fileListBox1.GetSelected(i) == true)
            {
                Args = "-i " + this.fileListBox1.get_Items(i) + " -r -c -noerr";
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoWork(ArgDir, ExeName, Args, "3"));
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
    }


    private static void DoWork(string WorkingDir, string exefile, string parameters, string priority)
    {
        Pool.WaitOne();

        Process exeProcess = new Process();
        int exitCode;

        try
        {
            exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exefile;
            exeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
            exeProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDir;
            exeProcess.Start();
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR EXECUTING: " + parameters + " " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            exitCode = exeProcess.ExitCode;
        }
        Pool.Release();
    }

}
```

The 3 main issues I am having:

1. the jobs don't always start in the correct order (some items lower in the ListBox are started before other items higher up)
2. sometimes the process kicked off seems to stall, as though it has completed but the window remains on the screen. This is a pretty consistent problem, but not always the same task/input file will stall.  Sometimes one that worked fine in a prior test will stall and visa versa.
3. my laptop reboots while testing this portion of the code??

Any feedback, links, examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do these worker processes overlap? As in, will the three processes step on each other while running? If not, then having three (or n) threads that access a single GetNextWorkItem() method that handles locking might be a simpler way to make sure that all steps start in order.

Comment: No, these processes s/b completely independent of 1 another.  I will look into GetNextWorkItem().  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no guarantees as to the order in which the threads will actually start up.  It is very possible that two threads started (in the `Thread.Start()` sense) in quick succession to one another may experience the "second" one actually beginning execution before the "first one."  If ordered execution is important, you will need to serialize their execution (which seems to obviate the need to start multiple threads.)
2. I am curious if you are sure that all of your processes are starting up with the proper input file name.  Your delegate usage looks to me like you could actually end up with two starting up with the same file and I'm wondering if this is contributing to your second issue.
3. How often?  Is your computer doing anything else at this time?  Do you get any messages, BSOD or any form of information?  This is not normal by any means.

Comment: 1. What should I consider using to mutli-thread AND be sure the order is correct?
2. I feel confident about the input files.  I'm only testing 1 set right now (approx 12 files) and I originally coded the functionality w/o threading and the processes ran as expected.  But if there is something I need to add to ensure the same 1 is not being passed twice please advise.  
3. It doesn't happen every test, but it's a fairly new laptop and I've only had the problem while testing this code.  I think if I can address issues 1 and 2 this one will be fixed... hopefully.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you want the order to be correct, you are effectively asking for serial execution, which means the only thing you gain from multithreading is overhead.  Now, this is not to say that each task itself may not run multithreaded internally, and there is no reason not to do that, but from an atomic task level, you effectively want them to be serial so unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: For #2, unless this already exists, put a debug print statement inside the `DoWork()` function to display the arguments, if you don't have this already.  I theorize that there is a chance that may be getting the same arguments to two invocations.

If this is happening, move the declaration of `string Args` inside your `if` block.  (So a few lines later than it is right now.)

Comment: Not 100% clear what u mean by serialize. Let me give more background. The task being kicked off (Oc2.exe) reads an infile and spits out file. If I were to run in order, 1 run may take 1 hour and a combined 11 others would take 1 hour (so 2 hours total). But when I use a .bat script (as I currently do) and kick off the larger file first and then run the other 11 (in order 1 at a time) it only takes slightly > 1 hr. The Oc2.exe runs are completely separate from my application and each other. I'm using my app just to schedule the tasks and run in order (with possible concurrency). Make sense??

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4.0 now offers some new tools for simple parallel tasks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987838(v=vs.100).aspx

```
    string ExeName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Norman\\bin\\OC2.exe";
    string Args;
    string ArgDir = "\\";

    //Simulated listbox items here:
    string[] filelist = new string[] {"file1", "file2"};

    System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions options = new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 10, options, (i => {

        Args = "-i " + filelist[i] + " -r -c -noerr";
        DoWork(ArgDir, ExeName, Args, "3");
    }
        ));
}
```

By using Parallel.For, you can manage the concurrency and the tasks should be initiated in order.

In .Net 2.0 you can use some BackgroundWorkers, and a simple controller method. Something like:

```
Stack<string> filelist = new Stack<string>() {"file1", "file2"};

private void Setup()
{

    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker2;

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

    backgroundWorker2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

private void Execute()
{
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork();
    backgroundWorker2.DoWork();
}

private string GetNextItem()
{
    //this is a crude controller
    return filelist.Pop();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    string nextFile = GetNextItem();
    //Some simple check here to see if there were any items left or quit
    ....
    //Now do work
    Args = "-i " + nextFile  + " -r -c -noerr";
    DoWork(ArgDir, ExeName, Args, "3");

}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{   
    // Check for errors...
    ...

    // See if more work to do
    if (filelist.Count > 0)
    {
        //Repeat task
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        worker.DoWork();
    }
}
```

With BackgroundWorkers you can also have independent progress bars and such.

Code is untested.

Comment: I started looking into this earlier, but my VS did not show .Net 4.0 as a target, even though I know I installed it. So on to another problem...  Thanks for the example!

Comment: Thanks, I'm still working on getting my VS2008 to acknowledge .NET 4 framework.  If I cannot get that working soon I'll look into your Background worker approach. However, at a glance, it appears I am limited to a specific/hard-coded number of background workers (2 in your example).  But I may need to study closer to see how this can be changed to a dynamic number. Thanks again for the example.

Comment: You can create a collection of background workers, it was just too much code to type in the example. That also gives you an easy way to manipulate them and to dispose of them.